# Intercept VSCode Markdown before being sent to preview

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there anyway to intercept the markdown before it is sent to preview?

I'm hoping to inject some bespoke code before it gets rendered

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Currently not, but for our next release we plan to provide API for extensions to write their own preview mechanism so that the content can be a generated markdown file with any additions as needed.

Comment: any idea when this will be released?